# Does spark computeSVD() function use QR factorization?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, svd

im new using pyspark and im using a `computeSVD()` and i am looking if this function use `QR factorization` method.

- here is `computeSVD()` [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/RowMatrix.scala#L328).

i would highely appriciate any information.